# Interacting between two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on a winform application, and my goal is to make a label on my form visible to the user, and three seconds later make the label invisible. The issue here is timing out three seconds. I honestly do not know if this was the correct solution to my problem, but I was able to make this work by creating a new thread, and having the new thread Sleep for three seconds (System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)).

#### I can't use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) because this freezes my GUI for 3 seconds!

```
private void someVoid()
{
     lbl_authenticationProcess.Text = "Credentials have been verified authentic...";

     Thread sleepThreadStart = new Thread(new ThreadStart(newThread_restProgram));
     sleepThreadStart.Start();

     // Once three seconds has passed / thread has finished: lbl_authenticationProcess.Visible = false;
}

private void newThread_restProgram()
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

So, back to my original question. How can I determine (from my main thread) when the new thread has completed, meaning three seconds has passed?

I am open to new ideas as well as I'm sure there are many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, you are blocking the entire UI thread in order to hide a label after 3 seconds. If that's what you want, then just user `Thread.Sleep(3000)` from within the form. If not, though, then you're best off using a `Timer`:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 3000;
timer.Tick += (s, e) => { this.lbl_authenticationProcess.Visible = false; timer.Stop(); }
timer.Start();
```

After 3 seconds, the label will disappear. While you're waiting for that, though, a user can still interact with your application.

Note that you *must* use the Forms version of `Timer`, since its `Tick` event is raised on the UI thread, allowing direct access to the control. Other timers *can* work, but interaction with the control would have to be `Invoke/BeginInvoke`d.

Comment: +1 For using a timer, that's the perfect way.  Why didn't I think of that, damn :(

Comment: It seems like this is the smartest decision. May I ask though, what is wrong with my original multithreading idea? It gave me the same effect (the GUI did NOT freeze up). I just wasn't sure about how to find out once the three seconds were up.

Comment: @Evan there's nothing wrong with your version *per se*, it's just that all you were doing was imitating a timer. But there's no need for that, since the `Timer` class already exists, and works well!

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question - I swear! What is the following line doing? 

timer.Tick += (s, e) => { this.lbl_authenticationProcess.Visible = false; }

I am mainly confused with the (s,e) => part, I have never seen this syntax before.

Comment: Won't the timer fire every three seconds... so if he runs this code more than once, there will be multiple timers each making the label invisible every three seconds?

Comment: @bob You're right, the event handler should call `.Stop()`. I will update.

Comment: @Evan That's just a quick way to set an event handler. That gibberish is a *lambda expression*, which is a quick way to declare a method in-place.

Comment: @dlev ... you are brilliant ... I'm going to accept your answer as it does EXACTLY what I need it to do ... but I can't find any documentation on (s,e) for a quick method of setting a new event handler. People on this site are so creative and bright it blows my mind.

Comment: @Evan Glad it works! Take a look at this link for a primer on lambdas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @dlev Ohhh, so the compiler actually knows what types the parameters "s" and "e" will be? If so, I can honestly say that I learned something new today :) I'm assuming the compiler can guess the parameter types as it's an event handler? If I were making a call to a custom method though I would most likely have to specify the types. Sound correct?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use Timer

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
t.Interval = 3000;
t.Start();
t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     label.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to synchronize anything.  You just need a new thread, with a reference to your label. Your code is actually pretty close:

```
private void someVoid()
{
     lbl_authenticationProcess.Text = "Credentials have been verified authentic...";
     lbl_authenticationProcess.Visible = true;

     Thread sleepThreadStart = new Thread(new ThreadStart(newThread_restProgram));
     sleepThreadStart.Start();
}

private void newThread_restProgram()
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
     if (lbl_authenticationProcess.InvokeRequired) {
         lbl_authenticationProcess.Invoke(new SimpleCallBack(makeInvisible));
     } else {
         makeInvisible();
     }
}

private void makeInvisible()
{
     lbl_authenticationProcess.Visible = false;
}
```

So, when someVoid() is called, the message on the label is set, the label is made visible.  Then a new thread is started with the newThread_restProgram() as the body.  The new thread will sleep for 3 seconds (allowing other parts of the program to run), then the sleep ends and the label is made invisible.  The new thread ends automatically because it's body method returns.

Comment: Okay, so in reality the only thing I was missing was a reference to my label from the new thread?

Comment: Forgot that you might have to set the Visible property on the UI thread.  Made a change to my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method like so:

```
public void SetLbl(string txt)
{
 Invoke((Action)(lbl_authenticationProcess.Text = txt));
}
```

And you would be able to call it from the second thread, but it invokes on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or older, it's kinda a pain:

```
 private void YourMethod()
 {
      someLabel.BeginInvoke(() =>
         {
              someLabel.Text = "Something Else";

              Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                 {
                       Thread.Sleep(3000);
                       someLabel.BeginInvoke(() => { someLabel.Visible = false; });
                 });

              thread.Start();
         });
 }
```

That should stop you from blocking the UI.

If you're using .NET 4+:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
           someLabel.BeginInvoke(() => { someLabel.Text = "Something" });
     }).ContinueWith(() =>
     {
         Thread.Sleep(3000);
         someLabel.BeginInvoke(() => { someLabel.Visible = false; });
     });
```

Comment: This is a really interesting post - give me a minute to digest it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to download the [Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9983) then you could use this really elegant solution which requires the new `async` and `await` keywords.<sup>1</sup>

```
private void async YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   // Do authentication stuff here.
   lbl_authenticationProcess.Text = "Credentials have been verified authentic...";
   await Task.Delay(3000); // TaskEx.Delay in CTP
   lbl_authenticationProcess.Visible = false;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>*Note that the Async CTP uses `TaskEx` instead of `Task`.*

Comment: This is a wonderful suggestion - and yes very elegant indeed - however I think the timer solutions works just fine for what I am doing, and does not require adding the extra "stuff" to my application.

Comment: @Evan: I don't blame you. I wouldn't want to add beta code to my application either. It will definitely be cool when C# 5.0 gets released though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AutoResetEvent` for your thread synchronization.  You set the event to signalled when your secondary thread has woken from it's sleep, so that it can notify your main thread.

That means though that your main thread waits for the other thread to complete.

On that note, you can use `SecondThread.Join()` to wait for it to complete in your main thread.

You do **either** of the above, but you don't need to do both.

As suggested in the comments, having a UI thread sleep is not generally a good idea, as it causes unresponsiveness for the user.

However if you do that, you might as well just sleep your main thread and get rid of the extraneous need of the second thread.

Comment: Are you suggesting that using SecondThread.Join() along with AutoResetEven will "pause" my GUI in the same way that Thread.Sleep() is doing?

Comment: You wouldn't want your UI thread to sleep... you'll lose the UI responsiveness

Comment: Basically yes, because with the waiting on the Event will halt your thread, until it is set to signalled, and Join() will wait until the thread you're joining on is completed before continuing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure this is the right way to do it, but to answer your question, you have to use the Join() function.

```
public void CallingThread()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(myWorkerThread);
    t.Join();
}

public void WorkerThread()
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

You can also add a timeout as parameter to the function, but you don't need that here.

Comment: dlev's answer seems the correct solution for what you want to do.